# Request body is undefined for POST request in KOA

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, koa

i am a beginner in nodejs. 
I am trying to create an HTTP server that uses koa framework for handling HTTP requests.
Following is the code for my server.

```
app.use(function * (next){
    var ctx = this;

    var resource = url.parse(ctx.request.url, true, true).pathname;
    switch(resource) {
            case '/':
                    resource = config.app.root + '/dist/index.html';
                    ctx.type = mime.lookup(resource);
                    ctx.body = fs.readFileSync(resource, 'utf-8');
                    ctx.response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    break;
            case '/fudge/contact':
                    console.log('============================');
                    console.log(ctx.request); // no body
                    console.log('============================');
                    console.log(ctx.req);     // no body
                    console.log('============================');
                    console.log(ctx.request.body) // is undefined
                    break;
            default:
                    resource = config.app.root + resource;
                    ctx.type = mime.lookup(resource);
                    ctx.body = fs.readFileSync(resource, 'utf-8');
                    ctx.response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    break;
    }});
```

As mentioned in the case '/fudge/contact' the ctx.request.body is undefined.
But, when I check for ctx.request or ctx.req, it shows content-length as 98(or something non-zero).

Following is the output that i get:

```
============================

{ 
method: 'POST',
  url: '/fudge/contact',
  header: 
   { host: 'localhost:9090',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0',
     accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
     referer: 'http://localhost:9090/',
     'content-length': '98',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     pragma: 'no-cache',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache'}}
============================
{ _readableState: 
   { objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
... more lines but no body.
============================
undefined
```

Following is the client code:
I have used HttpClient library of aurelia framework.

```
        contactUs(){
            this.http.createRequest('/fudge/contact')
                    .asPost()
                    .withBaseUri('http://localhost:9090')
                    .withHeader('Content-Type','text/plain')
                    .withContent('{"heading":this.heading, "firstName":this.firstName, "lastName":this.lastName, "query":this.query}')
                    .send();
            alert(`Thank you, ${this.fullName}, your query has been successfully submitted`);

    }
```

The above code is javascript - ES7 and is valid as I am using transpilers like Babel.
Point is that i am able to send POST request to server successfully, but there is no body in the request. Please suggest some solution.

Versions used:
Node v0.12.0,
Koa v0.19.1

Comment: using
ctx.request.on('data', function(data) {
// some code
});  event handler i was able to view the request body. But being asynchronous, the response was being sent to the client before i could process the request. So i went for koa-body which solved my problem.
I would still like to know the exact issue for better understanding. If anyone can help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Koa doesn't parse the request body by default, you need to add a middleware for body parsing, like [koa-body](https://github.com/dlau/koa-body) for example:

```
var app     = require('koa')(),
    router  = require('koa-router'),
    koaBody = require('koa-body');

app.use(router());

app.post('/users', koaBody(),
  function *(next) {
    console.log(this.request.body);
    // => POST body
    this.body = JSON.stringify(this.request.body);
  }
);
app.listen(3131)
console.log('curl -i http://localhost:3131/ -d "name=test"');
```

Koa's philosophy is to have as little as possible in the core framework, and let people compound their system by assembling specialized  middlewares. From what I have seen, there are a few different packages for parsing the request's body, some are simpler and others have more features/options (e.g. [koa-better-body](https://github.com/tunnckoCore/koa-better-body)).
It's all about giving choices to the developer without creating a big monolith.

While this approach may seem strange at first, I personally like it: it allows me to choose only the features I need without bloating the  framework with options for every possible use case.

Comment: Any specific reason for that behavior?

Comment: What is the use of a request with no body? Parsing body should have been an inbuilt feature. I 'll wait for a better answer.

Comment: Edited the answer to attempt to clarify that. But really, it's just a different framework with different design decisions than what one might usually  expect. And that's part of what makes it great.

Comment: Yes, Koa claims to have a lightweight framework. But I am not sure if they were willing to sacrifice such an obvious feature. I think I should ask koa team for more details. Till then I will mark your answer as helpful. :)